# How use AppleScript, to write to an Xcode file?

Tags: xcode, applescript, edit

Suppose I have an Xcode project open. (For example, suppose main.m is open for editing.) I'd like to write to the code using AppleScript.

The following AppleScript works fine with TextWranger:

```
set string_to_write to "asdf"
set string_size to count string_to_write

tell application "TextWrangler"
    activate
    set selection to string_to_write
    select insertion point after character string_size of selection
end tell
```

However, I can't get it to work with Xcode. (I changed the AppleScript to say
tell application "Xcode"
instead of
tell application "TextWrangler".)

The word "selection" in the AppleScript dictionary for Xcode, but AppleScript rejects each of the following commands:

```
selection
selection of document 1
character 1 of document 1
character 1 of source document
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to write to an Xcode source code file, using AppleScript?

I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 and TextWrangler 4.5.1. I got the same results running on Mac OS X version 10.8.5, and on 10.9.1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have a Xcode Project open and a source file selected I can get the properties with this:

```
tell application "Xcode"
    get properties of source document 1
end tell
```

Example Result:

> {contents:"sourceContent [snipped]", selected paragraph range:{14, 14}, name:"AppDelegate.h", selection:insertion point 272 of source document "AppDelegate.h" of application "Xcode"}

(hope it helps to fiddle around and translate that TextWrangler Syntax into Xcode's)

Comment: DigiMonk, thanks. (I'd upvote your answer if I had enough reputation points.) Looking at the properties, I still couldn't figure out how to write to an Xcode file, using "selected". (I'd still appreciate help with that.) If I told System Events to keystroke the string, newlines were lost. But this seems to work with Xcode and TextWrangler: Activate the output application, then copy the string to the clipboard, then `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down`.